# Shell script add user with variable

Tags: bash

So I have a shell script and I want to create a variable user

```
adduser -D -S -h /var/cache/nginx -s /sbin/nologin -G nginx $NGINX_USER
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Does it not work, or what is the question?

Comment: It was user error. I did not set $NGINX_USER variable properly

Answer (score 0):

Use the option `--force-badname`:

> --force-badname   allow usernames which do not match the
>                       NAME_REGEX[_SYSTEM] configuration variable

Also:

```
adduser -D -S -h /var/cache/nginx -s /sbin/nologin -G nginx $NGINX_USER --force-badname
```

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that `$NGINX_USER` will expand to such an invalid name, or that if it does so, the use of a bad name is intentional? (Keep in mind that shell expansions happens *before* the command is started, so `adduser` can't see the original command the OP typed -- they only see the new command created after expansion).

Comment: It was user error. I did not set $NGINX_USER variable properly